# Seamless texturing

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I imported the texture on my model and it cant lay seamless on a model. Any suggestions on how to fix it without harming the form of a curve?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unwrap the model again. What does the UV look like?

Comment: How do you want to texture your object? Is the texture supposed to follow the curve or is it supposed to be vertical or horizontal? Also maybe share your file so that we can give a try, don't forget to pack your texture: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

Most pro textures are built around the mesh + UV, rather than the UV being built around the texture.  If you don't want to do it that way, you don't have to-- just know, you're doing it backwards.  (Yes, there are unanticipated issues to doing it like that.  Like texture distortion and renderer-specific triangulation....  Which you will encounter during this project, but will eventually, probably, solve by increasing the vert count rather than dealing with the distortion.)

Now. you don't want to do it like that.  That's ok.  Why do you have that weird bridge at the right side of your wireframe?  You go from 8 verts to 16 verts.  If I'm counting correctly.  Then, at the end of your bend, you go back from from 16 verts to 8 verts.

Make your mesh a quad mesh-- no bridges to drop vert count, so no tris-- and you can do a follow active quads mapping.  Select face, select linked, u->follow active quads, enter.  Which will give you a seamless, follow-the-curve mapping for the dominant face.  (There is no such thing as a low-distortion, seamless mapping for the entire shape.  2D doesn't map to 3D like that, or else we wouldn't need all those cartographer projections.)

Next time, if you want, you can make this shape out of a curve object, or out of a mesh with a curve modifier, which means that you can use generated texture coords to get the same mapping instead of UV.